# Drag and drop images and merge them into one bitmap in Android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I want to program an Android app where I can select two images, one as background and one smaller above.
Then I want to drag and drop the smaller image using gestures on the touchscreen.
Finally I want to merge both images into one bitmap.

I already made an app where I can move a small picture around and another app where I can combine two images into one bitmap.

But atm I have no idea how to combine both - I already did a lot of research but it's either only moving or merging a picture.

Code from first app 'MovePicture' - MainActivity.java:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.graphics_holder);
        PlayAreaView image = new PlayAreaView(this);
        frame.addView(image);
    }

    private class PlayAreaView extends View {

        private GestureDetector gestures;
        private Matrix translate;
        private Bitmap picture;
        private Matrix animateStart;
        private Interpolator animateInterpolator;
        private long startTime;
        private long endTime;
        private float totalAnimDx;
        private float totalAnimDy;

        public void onAnimateMove(float dx, float dy, long duration) {
            animateStart = new Matrix(translate);
            animateInterpolator = new OvershootInterpolator();
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            endTime = startTime + duration;
            totalAnimDx = dx;
            totalAnimDy = dy;
            post(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    onAnimateStep();
                }
            });
        }

        private void onAnimateStep() {

            long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            float percentTime = (float) (curTime - startTime) / (float) (endTime - startTime);
            float percentDistance = animateInterpolator.getInterpolation(percentTime);
            float curDx = percentDistance * totalAnimDx;
            float curDy = percentDistance * totalAnimDy;
            translate.set(animateStart);
            onMove(curDx, curDy);

            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "We're " + percentDistance + " of the way there!");
            if (percentTime < 1.0f) {
                post(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        onAnimateStep();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        public void onMove(float dx, float dy) {
            translate.postTranslate(dx, dy);
            invalidate();
        }

        public void onResetLocation() {
            translate.reset();
            invalidate();
        }

        public void onSetLocation(float dx, float dy) {
            translate.postTranslate(dx, dy);
        }

        public PlayAreaView(Context context) {

            super(context);
            translate = new Matrix();
            gestures = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureListener(this));
            picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cem);
        }


        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "onDraw");
            canvas.drawBitmap(picture, translate, null);
            Matrix m = canvas.getMatrix();
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Matrix: " + translate.toShortString());
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Canvas: " + m.toShortString());
        }

        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            return gestures.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

    }


    private class GestureListener implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

        PlayAreaView view;

        public GestureListener(PlayAreaView view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "onDown");
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, final float velocityX, final float velocityY) {

            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "onFling");
            final float distanceTimeFactor = 0.4f;
            final float totalDx = (distanceTimeFactor * velocityX / 2);
            final float totalDy = (distanceTimeFactor * velocityY / 2);

            view.onAnimateMove(totalDx, totalDy, (long) (1000 * distanceTimeFactor));

            return true;
        }

        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTap");
            view.onResetLocation();
            return true;
        }

        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "onLongPress");
        }

        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {

            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "onScroll");
            view.onMove(-distanceX, -distanceY);
            return true;
        }

        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "onShowPress");
        }

        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapUp");
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTapEvent");
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapConfirmed");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Code from second app 'MergePicture' - MainActivity.java:

```
ImageView img;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mergedPhoto);
}

public void buttonMerge(View view) throws IOException {

    Bitmap bigImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img1);
    Bitmap smallImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img2);
    Bitmap mergedImages = createSingleImageFromMultipleImages(bigImage, smallImage);


    File f = new File("/storage/emulated/0/test.png");

    OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
    mergedImages.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
    os.close();

    img.setImageBitmap(mergedImages);
}

private Bitmap createSingleImageFromMultipleImages(Bitmap firstImage, Bitmap secondImage){

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(firstImage.getWidth(), firstImage.getHeight(), firstImage.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawBitmap(firstImage, 0f, 0f, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(secondImage, 50, 1000, null);
    return result;
}
```

I'm not sure how to combine both - I know I have to get the coordinates from the image after moving and use them instead of the hardcoded 50/1000 values.

Just using a FrameLayout with "android:background="@drawable/background">" in the first apps XML is wrong too.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, you want your bitmap to have the background, as well and the 'movable' image on top of it. If so, you can achieve this using canvas. Try this out..

Kotlin snippet..

```
//frame is the parent framelayout in your activity where both the background and the image is placed 
fun mergeImages(frame: FrameLayout): Bitmap {

    //Create the bitmap and the canvas
    val mergedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(frame.width, frame.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(mergedBitmap)

    //get the background image first
    val backgroundImage = frame.background

    //draw the background on the canvas
    backgroundImage.draw(canvas)

    //finally draw your view on the canvas
    frame.draw(canvas)

    return mergedBitmap
}
```